innodb fetch time, not query execution time
A very basic query but from a huge table
SELECT profile_id FROM clients WHERE is_vip = 0

execution has a duration of 0.716s and data fetch time of 15.072s
Obviously my question is if I can speed this up somehow. Both profile_id, and is_vip have indexes, not that it matters since the execution time is fast. Number of returned rows are 4.6M+ and growing. For more background info the engine is innodb, where clause is dynamic but for every scenario the table was optimized so the execution time is below 1s, only the data fetching is slow, so the where clause can also be created_at < '2024-12-01'.
Before someone mentions that it's not normal to fetch this much data in one go without pagination I want to mention that the data is not sent to a front end (user) but to a third party api for further processing.
If the only answer is I just have to wait it out I'm also open to suggestions on modifying the structure of storage if it means improved retrieval time.

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE, EXPLAIN SELECT ... and tell us what the client is doing with 4.6M rows.

Networks are fast, but not infinitely fast. There is a rate of data transfer over a network, and you can do the math.
For example, 4.6M rows, assuming on average 40 bytes per row, that's about 175MB.
The time to transfer 175MB over for example a 100Mbit network can be calculated... it turns out the minimum transfer time is about 15 seconds.
If your data volume increases, or the network is congested by other traffic, it could take longer.
As you said, query optimization won't help. The time is mostly due to the data transfer, not executing the query to produce the result.
You can:

Avoid the network by using the MySQL socket interface. This is somewhat faster than the TCP interface, but it only works for clients on the same server as the database. So in your case, since you are doing this to transfer data to a third party, it won't help.

Upgrade the speed of the network between the client and your MySQL server. The figures I gave above are for a 100Mbit network, which is old and I don't see it used much anymore within a datacenter network. But it might match the throughput of a WAN connection. You can investigate if it's possible to get a faster network link. I have no idea what your current network is, so I can't advise on that.

Decrease the size of data transferred. The example I gave is for a 40-bytes-per-row payload. Can you decrease this? For example, omit columns that are not needed by the client. Or change data types of each column to the most compact type that supports the data you need to represent. Read the MySQL manual on data type storage for details. Again, you haven't shown what data types you currently have, or the query you are currently using, so I can't suggest any specific changes.

Use the compressed protocol. This may not be practical, depending on how the client connects. Read about it.


Ultimately, transferring large amounts of data takes time. There's no magic spell you can use to change the laws of physics.

Mysql server is an aws aurora instance so I don't think socket interface is available. Data type is unsigned integer, a single column is retrieved so there is no way to decrease that. I'm not familiar with compressed protocol so I'm going to check that, thanks.

Yes, Aurora does not allow local access, because you have no direct access to the server, only access via TCP. If the values in your integer column are always between 0 and 65535, then you could use SMALLINT UNSIGNED. There's also a MEDIUMINT, but don't bother with that, I'm told by MySQL engineers that MEDIUMINT takes 4 bytes just like INT. Good luck!

If this is the query:
SELECT profile_id FROM clients WHERE is_vip = 0

Then, INDEX(is_vip, profile_id) is the best you can do to improve speed. You say, "Both profile_id and is_vip have indexes" -- That is not as good.  Drop the is_vip when adding my suggested index.
If it still takes 15 seconds, so be it.
